# Read functions in Lisp aren't prompting

Tags: input, lisp, common-lisp, lispworks

So I recently taught myself lisp and have been messing around with some programs. I am trying to write a small program that compares a list of user-entered classes and finds which ones can work together. Below is the first part that collects the data from the user and creates some lists of when the class is.

```
(defun class-entries ()

(setf Monday 0)                                                                                     ;initializes the days of the week 
(setf Tuesday 0)
(setf Wednesday 0)
(setf Thursday 0)
(setf Friday 0)

 (setf times 100)
 (dotimes (repeating times "You have reached the limit of entries")                                  ;repeats the following for the number of classes that you are comparing
  (dolist (dayofweek '(Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday))                                    ;repeats the following for each day of the week
   (print (concatenate 'string "Does this class occur on " dayofweek " ?"))  
    (setf isday (read))
   (if (= isday 1)                                                                                   ;prompts the questions if there is a class that day
    (progn
     (print (concatenate 'string "What time does the class begin on " dayofweek " ?"))
     (setf starttime (read))
     (print (concatenate 'string "What time does the class end on " dayofweek " ?"))
     (setf endtime (read)))
     (setf isday 0))
   (if (= isday 0)                                                                                    ;Adds the list of (startime endtime) to the current day of week or nil if there isn't a class that day
    (setf 'dayofweek '"nil")
    (setf 'dayofweek '(starttime endtime))))
 (print "What is the title of the class?")
 (setf (read) '((mon (Monday)) (tues (Tuesday)) (wed (Wednesday)) (thurs (Thursday)) (fri (friday)))) ;sets a new variable to the values of the classes's hours
  (print "Is there another class?")                                                                   ;repeats the function for another class or ends it
   (setf isclass (read))
   (if (= isclass 0)
    (setf times 0)
    ()))
 (setf times 100)
)
```

When I evaluate the function it only returns 0 and nothing else appears. I'm not sure if it's because I am not using Listener or what. Thanks.

Comment: `(setf (read) ...)` doesn't make sense. `(read)` isn't a place that you can assign  to. Is this really compiling without error?

Comment: You also shouldn't be using global variables in a function. You should use `let` to bind local variables, not `setf` to assign global variables.

Comment: When you assign a variable, you shouldn't quote the variable. `(setf 'dayofweek '(starttime endtime))` should be `(setf dayofweek (list starttime endtime))`

Comment: (setf (read) was meant to assign a variable that the user immediately supplied the name for. Yes there is no error. But there might be something up because user input isn't working. I will try to use local variable more, thanks. I quoted that variable because I thought that would make it insert the value of that variable in as the name. Since that line is in the function (dolist), the value of dayofweek should be one of the days, and the hope is that the day being processed has its value set to '(starttime endtime).

Comment: You seem to have some fundamental misunderstandings about when variables are evaluated or not. Variables aren't evaluated inside quoted lists.

Comment: `(setf <place> <value>)` doesn't evaluate `<place>` to get a variable to assign.

Comment: If you want to let the user tell you which variable to set, you do `(setf variable (read)) (setf (symbol-value variable) <value>)`

Comment: There are so many errors in your code, it's hard to know where to start.

Comment: Here is a Lisp book to learn the basics: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/

Comment: Note that output maybe buffered. To make sure the output is on the screen use (finish-output).

Comment: For things like **(setf isday (read))**, note that Common Lisp already provides [**yes-or-no-p** and **y-or-n-p**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_y_or_n.htm) that return a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the question is specified enough, but this may help you a bit, and hopefully serves as a useful example for decomposition and prompting.  It's not too hard to add some additional checks to things:

```
(defun prompt (&optional (control "> ") &rest arguments)
  "Read a value from STREAM after presenting PROMPT."
  (fresh-line *terminal-io*)
  (apply 'format *terminal-io* control arguments)
  (finish-output *terminal-io*)
  (read *terminal-io*))

(defstruct course
  (name nil :type symbol :read-only t)
  (day nil :type symbol :read-only t)
  (start nil :type number :read-only t)
  (end nil :type number :read-only t))

(defun prompt-for-course ()
  (flet ((except-quit (x)
           (if (string-equal (princ-to-string x) "quit")
               (return-from prompt-for-course nil)
               x)))
    (let (name day start end)
      (setq name  (except-quit (prompt "course name: "))
            day   (except-quit (prompt "course day:  "))
            start (except-quit (prompt "start time:  "))
            end   (except-quit (prompt "end time:    ")))
      (make-course :name name
                   :day day
                   :start start
                   :end end))))

(defun prompt-for-courses ()
  (loop
     with courses = (make-hash-table)
     for course = (prompt-for-course)
     while course
     do (push course (gethash (course-day course) courses))
     finally (return courses)))
```

```
CL-USER> (prompt-for-courses)
course name: intro-logic
course day:  monday
start time:  1100
end time:    1250

course name: intermediate-logic
course day:  tuesday
start time:  1100
end time:    1250

course name: quit

#<HASH-TABLE :TEST EQL :COUNT 2 {1003EA6513}>
```